# PHP library to download the HTML of a completely loaded webpage including AJAX-added parts

Tags: javascript, html, php, url

I need some piece of PHP script (or function) that can load a complete webpage including AJAX parts and images, I mean by giving the URL it returns me a complete HTML.

Up to now i have used "simple_html_dom" and some Curl based functions but none of these work for AJAX parts.

For this to work, the library probably has to simulate a browser with JavaScript, load the page and wait for all elements to load/transform, before taking the HTML.

It must be free, ideally open source.

Comment: What do you mean `can load a complete web page`? cURL will easily return you all the HTML content. If you really want to make a perfect copy with scripts and css running perfectly the easiest way might simply be to make an `iframe`.

Comment: I mean some script(or program) that can simulate browser and send javascript requests and get all the html code and then return all of the gathered HTML.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) headless browser, and it's great for doing this sort of thing - everything a browser does is provided to a scripting language instead of a GUI.  I suspect much of the reason it works so well is that it uses the same V8 JavaScript-engine as Chrome... shame that's the wrong scripting-language for you...

I notice someone has created some PHP bindings to the Phantom API in a package called [PHP PhantomJS](http://jonnnnyw.github.io/php-phantomjs/).  I haven't used it because I've never needed this functionality from PHP, but that's certainly the route I'd be looking into going down if I wanted to used a headless browser within PHP.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this I would use **[Snoopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/)**

> Snoopy is a PHP class that simulates a web browser. It automates the task of retrieving web page content and posting forms, for example.

To get started, I would check out [This Guide](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/snoopy-example.htm), please tell me if it works out

Comment: Snnopy looks like 37KB of nicely laid-out PHP code to me?  I've only had a quick glance, but I'm pretty sure it can't run JavaScript, unfortunately.